# Unable to execute Processing nativecentroid in python standalone scripts using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, shell

I am using QGIS 3.2 on Windows7. I had successfully set all enviroment variables in `OSGeo4W` shell. I have run small scripts without any issue.
I have to run

```
processing.run('native:centroids', {'INPUT':'C:/Test/demand/valid.shp','ALL_PARTS':True,'OUTPUT':'C:/Test/demand/centroid.shp'})
```

The above line works perfectly in console within QGIS. But when I try to run in standalone scripts it is giving following error:

[image]

Although, in my script I have added below lines and I was able to execute `processing.run('qgis:voronoipolygons', parameters)`

```
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *
```

I don't understand where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please remember to always include the entire error message *as text, in the body of the question*. This will assure that the message is legible on all display devices,  and will permit indexing for free text search, so that others can find your answer.

Comment: I will keep this in mind henceforth

Answer (score 3):

I got my mistake. The below lines should be added before calling native algorithms. It works fine now.

```
 from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
 QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())
```